# sequelize - Where clause with associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

In sequelize I have boards and users setup, with a many to many association as follows

```
User.hasMany(Board, {through: BoardUsers});
Board.hasMany(User, {through:BoardUsers});
```

Is there anyway that, using a where clause I can find users that belong to one of a list of boards. For example, lets says I have 3 boards and I would like to find the first 20 users (using the default sort order) who belong to either board 1 or 3. Is there a way to do this without executing separate finds for each board, then manually combining the results.

I would love to be able to do something like:

```
User.findAll({where:{board: [1,3]}});
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

As far as I can tell the equivalent SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN (SELECT userID FROM boardusers WHERE boardId IN (1,3))
```

But I would love to be able to do it through the ORM.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure if you can do this directly, you can always query for `Boards` and eagerly fetch users.

Something along these lines:

```
Board.findAll({where: {id: [1,3]}}, { include: [ User ] })
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it's impossible to get let's say the first 20 users (combined) in alphabetical order. Because the Users are a subset of the Boards you can't limit or sort them as a group.

Comment: @MarcMailhot Yes, it's pretty limited. Looks like you can actually filter the eagerly fetched rows, but there doesn't seem to be a way to filter the results by those eagerly fetched rows.

Comment: It looks like I might just end up writing the SQL by hand. I gave it a shot and it seems to work, it's just a little inconvenient/clunky/ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a late response but just had this same question, and here's how I got it to work in Sequelize 3.24.0 (something like this);

```
User.findAll({ include: [{ model: Board, where: { $in: [1,3] }}] });
```